# String in DataFrame are wired in Pandas python

Tags: string, csv, pandas, dataframe

I got an Dataframe as follow, it read from an csv file.

```
   COMPOUND  CELL_LINE         AUC
0  'ADAM17'     'A549'   97.228927
1  'ADAM17'    'BT-20'   75.409415
2  'ADAM17'   'BT-549'   66.641992
3  'ADAM17'  'CAL-120'   82.707886
4  'ADAM17'  'CAL-148'   59.822385
5  'ADAM17'   'CAL-51'   79.014796
6  'ADAM17'   'CAMA-1'   66.700791
7  'ADAM17'   'Calu-3'  302.225056
8  'ADAM17'   'Calu-6'   99.496544
```

where I index `AUC.iloc[0,0]`.  it give me  `'ADAM17'`.
and I try the test    `AUC.iloc[0,0] == 'ADAM17'`   the result is `False`.

what happend.

the second question how to read the csv file and directly become the following string without the single quote

```
  COMPOUND CELL_LINE         AUC
0   ADAM17      A549   97.228927
1   ADAM17     BT-20   75.409415
2   ADAM17    BT-549   66.641992
3   ADAM17   CAL-120   82.707886
4   ADAM17   CAL-148   59.822385
5   ADAM17    CAL-51   79.014796
6   ADAM17    CAMA-1   66.700791
7   ADAM17    Calu-3  302.225056
8   ADAM17    Calu-6   99.496544
```

Comment: bu the way. in my original csv file. the string is already with single quote, which I want to remove in Dataframe.    orignal file: COMPOUND CELL_LINE AUC
'ADAM17' 'BT-20' 84.86402756
'ADAM17' 'BT-549' 69.95587388
'ADAM17' 'CAL-120' 70.06211297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need add double `""`, because if you have only one `''`, it is read as `string` without `quotes`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""COMPOUND,CELL_LINE,AUC
'ADAM17','A549',97.228927
'ADAM17','BT-20',75.409415
'ADAM17','BT-549',66.641992
'ADAM17','CAL-120',82.707886
'ADAM17','CAL-148',59.822385
'ADAM17','CAL-51',79.014796
'ADAM17','CAMA-1',66.700791
'ADAM17','Calu-3',302.225056
'ADAM17','Calu-6',99.496544"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
AUC = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))

print AUC
   COMPOUND  CELL_LINE         AUC
0  'ADAM17'     'A549'   97.228927
1  'ADAM17'    'BT-20'   75.409415
2  'ADAM17'   'BT-549'   66.641992
3  'ADAM17'  'CAL-120'   82.707886
4  'ADAM17'  'CAL-148'   59.822385
5  'ADAM17'   'CAL-51'   79.014796
6  'ADAM17'   'CAMA-1'   66.700791
7  'ADAM17'   'Calu-3'  302.225056
8  'ADAM17'   'Calu-6'   99.496544

print AUC.iloc[0,0] == 'ADAM17'
False
print AUC.iloc[0,0] == "ADAM17"
False
print AUC.iloc[0,0] == "'ADAM17'"
True
```

You can add parameter `quotechar="'"` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for removing `''`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""COMPOUND,CELL_LINE,AUC
'ADAM17','A549',97.228927
'ADAM17','BT-20',75.409415
'ADAM17','BT-549',66.641992
'ADAM17','CAL-120',82.707886
'ADAM17','CAL-148',59.822385
'ADAM17','CAL-51',79.014796
'ADAM17','CAMA-1',66.700791
'ADAM17','Calu-3',302.225056
'ADAM17','Calu-6',99.496544"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),  quotechar="'")
print df
  COMPOUND CELL_LINE         AUC
0   ADAM17      A549   97.228927
1   ADAM17     BT-20   75.409415
2   ADAM17    BT-549   66.641992
3   ADAM17   CAL-120   82.707886
4   ADAM17   CAL-148   59.822385
5   ADAM17    CAL-51   79.014796
6   ADAM17    CAMA-1   66.700791
7   ADAM17    Calu-3  302.225056
8   ADAM17    Calu-6   99.496544
```